# Transition Property is not working well in tailwind css with next js

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create something like the discord navigation in tailwind css but I'm unable to animate it like that. I have applied the transition property but it just won't work. I have tried it in css too, but to no avail.

Here's the code:

```
<li className="relative w-12 h-12 bg-grey rounded-full overflow-hidden cursor-pointer  transition-all hover:rounded-2xl">
        <Image fill alt="Discord" src={server.icon} />
</li>
```

I want it like the discord side navigation but what I get is a very fast animation and with a delay for some reason. I've tried to reduce the speed but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

transition-all class style following image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qt74v.png)

You may use this classes for reduce duration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnIwP.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've tried everything but nothing seems to work. I also tried to increase the duration but to no avail

Comment: the duration property is just increasing the delay between the actual animation